# calling function with array parameters in c++ dll from Delphi

Tags: c++, arrays, delphi, dll

I'm having trouble calling a function in a c++ dll from delphi.

The c++ function is defined as following

```
BALL_SCRUB_DLL_API int CALLING_CONVENTION bsl2_ModelBallFlight(float cam_X, 
    float cam_Y, 
    float cam_Z, 
    Ball3d* ball_data_in, 
    int n_balls_in, 
    Ball3d* ball_data_out, 
    int &n_balls_out);
```

The ball struct looks as follows:

```
  typedef struct 
  { float X;
  float Y;
  float Z;
  float VX;
  float VY;
  float VZ;
  int frame_id;
  int flag;
  } Ball3d;
```

I want to send an array of ball_data_in from my delphi app and the c++ dll will return the same array type but with modified values in ball_data_out.

I have defined a TBall3D record as follows:

```
TBall3D = record
    X : Single;
    Y : Single;
    Z : Single;
    VX : Single;
    VY : Single;
    VZ : Single;
    Framecount : Integer;
    BallFlag : Integer;
  end;
  PBall3D = ^TBall3D;
  TBall3DArray = array of TBall3D;
  PBall3DArray = ^TBall3DArray;
```

My function declration looks as follows:

```
  TBSL2_ModelBallFlight = function( const Cam_X, Cam_Y, Cam_Z : Single;
                                    const ball_data_in : PBall3DArray;
                                    const NFramesIn : Integer;
                                    var ball_data_out : PBall3DArray;
                                    const NFramesOut : Integer) : Integer; cdecl;
```

How do i make that call from delphi to the dll? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
TBall3DArray = array of TBall3D;
```

That is a dynamic array. Which is a Delphi data type which is not appropriate for interop. You can use dynamic arrays to hold the data, but not as parameters across the interop boundary. In any case, a dynamic array variable is a pointer to the first element. But you are passing the address of that pointer which is one level of indirection too many.

Declare the import like this:

```
TBSL2_ModelBallFlight = function(
  Cam_X: Single;
  Cam_Y: Single;
  Cam_Z: Single;
  ball_data_in: PBall3D;
  NFramesIn: Integer;
  ball_data_out: PBall3D;
  var NFramesOut: Integer
): Integer; cdecl;
```

This is a direct translation of the C++ code. Where the C++ code uses `Ball3d*`, a pointer to `Ball3d`, you use `PBall3D`, a pointer to `TBall3D`.

Note also the nuance of the final parameter. In the C++ code it is `int &n_balls_out`. That is a reference to `int`. So make it a `var` parameter in Delphi.

In order to call the code you can use your dynamic array type. Declare variables for the in and out data:

```
var
  ball_data_in, ball_data_out: TBall3DArray;
```

You will need to initialise the arrays with calls to `SetLength`. And then when you pass the parameters do so either with `@ball_data_in[0]` or `PBall3D(ball_data_in)`. And likewise for the out parameter.

I don't know the precise protocol for the function, since a prototype is seldom enough, but the call might look like this:

```
SetLength(ball_data_in, NFramesIn);
SetLength(ball_data_out, NFramesOut);
retval := bsl2_ModelBallFlight(..., PBall3D(ball_data_in), NFramesIn, 
  PBall3D(ball_data_out), NFramesOut);
```

Comment: +1. Nicely written. I much prefer the readability and clarity of `PBall3D(ball_data_in)` rather than the `@ball_data_in[0]` syntax.

Comment: Thank you @Ken. Not original. I learnt it here on the stack from Remy or Arnaud, can't remember which. Possibly from both of them! Learning things like that is why I'm here.